# Search File in a directory

Tags: c++, mfc

How to find a specific file in a directory or folder?

I just have made a function and trying to pass directory path and file to be searched

```
BOOL CCalibrTreeView :: SearchFile(const CString &directory,const CString &filename)
{
    CFileFind finder;
}
```

I just want if file is there in the directory then `return true` else `return false`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to find specific file, you can use

```
CString strPath =_T("C:\\abc.txt");
if(PathFileExists(strPath)) // pass full path
{
 //file exists
}
else
{
 //file not exists
}
```

if file exists it will return true else it will return false.

[`PathFileExists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773584(v=vs.85).aspx) function
Determines whether a path to a file system object such as a file or folder is valid or not.

Comment: Correct. Also, if necessary you may need to `#include <shlwapi.h>` and link with `shlwapi.lib`.

Comment: @RogerRowland thanks for giving more details. I linked msdn link also so that he can get full details.